# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1,

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I wrote following stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 and I get error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_InsertCustTrans, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near '@TrID'.

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertCustTrans] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@CuID int, @TrType nvarchar(10), @TrAmt int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @TrID int;
    Select @TrID = MAX(TransactionID) from CustTrans;
    if Isnull(@TrID)
        @TrID = @TrID + 1
    else
        @TrID = 1

-- Insert statements for procedure here
if (@TrType = 'Deposit')
    begin
        INSERT INTO CustTrans (TransactionID, TransactionDate, CustID, TransactonType, CreditAmount)
            Values(@TrID, GetDate(), @CuID, @TrType, @TrAmt);
    end
else
    begin
        INSERT INTO CustTrans (TransactionID, TransactionDate, CustID, TransactonType, DebitAmount)
            Values(@TrID, GetDate(), @CuID, @TrType, @TrAmt);
    end
END
GO
```

Comment: Manually incrementing IDs is a horrible idea and open to race conditions. I assume you have a synchronization plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All assignment operations must be preceded by the keyword `set`.

```
Set @TrID = @TrID + 1
```

Also you are using IsNull incorrectly as Ivan points out.
The proper usage is:

```
If @TrID Is Null
```

Comment: I have another problem not able to check value:
If (@TrID = 'Deposit')
It goes to else condition. What can be reason for this?

Comment: I am able to solve this problem. In fact it was error on my side: I was passing value to @TrID instead of checking it. So, I has to be 'If (@TrID == 'Deposit').